# Which H264 (AVC or SVC) uses Firefox WebRTC?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, h.264, webrtc

Could you clarify which H264  (AVC or SVC)  uses media.gmp-gmpopenh264?
Will it possible to communicate with Firefox via WebRTC if a device supports only H264 AVC?

Comment: This is only one. h.264 and AVC are synonyms. They mean the exact same thing. SVC in this context is probably Scaleable Video Coding, and completely different. Not sure how it factors into your question. And finally, i don't recemond using openh264 for anything

Comment: Firefox includes Cisco's H.264AVC binary implementation (AVC) - see openh264.org

Answer (score 0):

This answer is not from me but from a person I met at the meetup here in Mountain View:

> GMP OpenH264 plugin only supports H264 AVC. So yes it will be possible to communicate with H264 AVC only devices.

Answer (score 0):

firefox supports only h.264 AVC.
h.264 SVC is backward compatible with AVC (the base layer of SVC is AVC) so an h.264 SVC capable device is also always an h.264 AVC capable device.

Comment: In practice this is rarely the case. The base layer is generally so low in quality that you're looking at terrible resolution. Microsoft, Cisco and others spend millions on developing servers that bridge this gap - they would not do so if it "just worked"

Comment: The question was about the *capacity* to communicate, not the quality of the resulting communication. I think I answered the question. This is true that the base layer is usually of low resolution though, so using SVC in AVC-backward compatibility case will result in a degraded experience.